# Why the var keep the details only at the second loop?

Tags: javascript, json

I have some problem to get the value height and the img in the first iteration, and I really can not understand where that delayed. I just started learning programming so I am sorry if my question is very simple for you.
My HTML shows the list of Pokémon and when I click I get the name and undefined, the height and the image URL is not shown.
Thanks for any of your help.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>Simple JS App</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='modal-container'></div>
<main>
    <div>
        <ul class="pokemon-list"></ul>
    </div>
</main>
<script src="js/promise-polyfill.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="js/tota11y.min.js"></script>
</body>

var pokemonRepository = (function () {
    var pokemonList = [];
    var apiUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=150';
    var pokemontDetails = [];

    function add(item) {
        pokemonList.push(item);
    }
    function getAll() {
        return pokemonList;
    }
    function addDetails() {
        pokemontDetails.push(item);
    }
    
    function loadList() {
        return fetch(apiUrl).then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function (json) {
            json.results.forEach(function (item) {
                var pokemon = {
                    name: item.name,
                    detailsUrl: item.url
                };
                add(pokemon);
            })
        }).catch(function (e) {
            console.error(e);
        })
    }

    function loadDetails(item) {
        var url = item.detailsUrl;
        return fetch(url).then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function (details) {
            // Now we add the details to the item
            item.imageUrl = details.sprites.front_default;
            item.height = details.height;
            item.types = details.types;
            return item;

        }).catch(function (e) {
            console.error(e);
        });
    }
    
    function showDetails(item) {
        loadDetails(item).then(function () {
        })
    }

    function showModal(pokemon) {
        var modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container');
        // Clear all existing modal content
        modalContainer.innerHTML = ''; //
        var modal = document.createElement('div');
        modal.classList.add('modal');
        // Add the new modal content
        var closeButtonElement = document.createElement('button');
        closeButtonElement.classList.add('modal-close');
        closeButtonElement.innerText = 'Close';
        closeButtonElement.addEventListener('click', hideModal);
        var titleElement = document.createElement('h1');
        titleElement.innerText = pokemon.name;
        var contentElement = document.createElement('p');
        contentElement.innerText = pokemon.height;
        let imageElement = document.createElement('img');
        imageElement.classList.add('pokemon-image');
        modal.appendChild(closeButtonElement);
        modal.appendChild(titleElement);
        modal.appendChild(contentElement);
        modal.appendChild(imageElement);
        modalContainer.appendChild(modal);
        modalContainer.classList.add('is-visible');
        modalContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            var target = e.target;
            console.log(e.target)
            if (target === modalContainer) {
                hideModal();
            }
        });
    }

    function addListItem(pokemone) {
        var container = document.querySelector('.pokemon-list');
        var listItem = document.createElement('li');
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerText = pokemone.name;
        container.appendChild(listItem); 
        listItem.appendChild(button);
        button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            showModal(pokemone);
        });
    }



    function hideModal() {
        var modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container');
        modalContainer.classList.remove('is-visible');
    }



    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        var modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container');
        if (e.key === 'Escape' && modalContainer.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
            hideModal();
        }
    });

    return{
        add: add,
        getAll: getAll,
        loadList: loadList,
        loadDetails: loadDetails,
        showDetails: showDetails,
        showModal: showModal,
        hideModal: hideModal,
        addListItem: addListItem,

    };
})();


    pokemonRepository.loadList().then(function () {
    pokemonRepository.getAll().forEach(function (pokemon) {
        pokemonRepository.addListItem(pokemon);
    })
    });
```

Comment: Hey, can you also post your *html*?

Comment: yes thanks, just updated my post.

Comment: So your problem is that the height and the image is not shown, correct?

Comment: yes, correct have you noticed anything?

Comment: the hight appears after the second clicks on the same button.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't check it, as I don't have your css styles. But the height is undefined because the pokemon object only has two properties, `name` and `detailsUrl`, but no height. Also, you don't pass a `src` prop to the image, that is why it isn't displayed. Where do you expect the height to come from?

Comment: thanks for your time, the height is in the pokemonRepository list, I noticed now that I do get all the details but only in the second click and not in the first one. For some reason, I get in the first irritation undefined.

Comment: In the then of your `loadList()` function, you specify the object `pokemon` only with the props `name` and `detailsUrl`. Seems to me that you should call `loadDetails()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your time, that's was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

*Here the full answer, as it is currently hidden in the comments*

In the then of your `loadList()` function, you specify the object `pokemon` only with the props `name` and `detailsUrl`. You should call `loadDetails()` instead, as it has the additional props you are missing.